# Custom model collection return false

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created a custom model with his collection but when i try to get the collection it returns false

```
$categorie = Mage::getModel("planet/categories")->getCollection(); // return false
```

Above, all the code I've wrote :

*app/code/local/Anas/Planet/etc/config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
      <Anas_Planet>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
      </Anas_Planet>
    </modules>
    <global>
    <models>
        <planet>
        <class>Anas_Planet_Model</class>
        <ressourceModel>planet_resource</ressourceModel>
        </planet>
        <planet_resource>
        <class>Anas_Planet_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <categories>
            <table>planet_categories</table>
            </categories>
        </entities>
        </planet_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <planet_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Anas_Planet</module>
            <class>Anas_Planet_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
        </planet_setup>
        <planet_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
        </planet_write>
        <planet_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
        </planet_read>
    </resources>
    <helpers>
        <planet>
        <class>Anas_Planet_Helper</class>
        </planet>
    </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

*app/code/local/Anas/Planet/Model/Categories.php*

```
class Anas_Planet_Model_Categories extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('planet/categories');
    }

}
```

*app/code/local/Anas/Planet/Model/Resource/Categories.php*

```
class Anas_Planet_Model_Resource_Categories extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract {

    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('planet/categories', '_id');
    }

}
```

*app/code/local/Anas/Planet/Model/Resource/Categories/Collection.php*

```
class Anas_Planet_Model_Resource_Categories_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract {

    protected function _construct() {
       $this->_init('planet/categories');
    }

}
```

Someone know where is my mistake?

Comment: Does `Mage::getModel("planet/categories")->load($id)` work for some existant id in db?

Comment: No I got    Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object

Comment: Perhaps your module isn't loaded to config? Did you create module xml file under etc/modules and does your module shown in list of modules under system/config/advanced in backend?

Comment: The module is successfully loaded because when I try : `$categorie = Mage::getModel("planet/categories");
 echo get_class($categorie);`
I got : `Anas_Planet_Model_Categories`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think now that this is simple typo. Try `resourceModel` instead of `ressourceModel` in your config.xml.

Comment: OMG It was just this! I always do this mistake because in french resource is ressource.